# Can we use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create and hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update both in hibernate.cfg.xml file

Tags: java, hibernate

Can we use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create and hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update both in hibernate.cfg.xml file?what happen if we use both create and update with each other.Please suggest i am confused.if i don't write any of them what will be default value.

Answer (score 1):

we cannot use  `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create and hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` both in hibernate.cfg.xml file

create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
update: update the schema if it exists or create new schema if it doesnot exist.

Comment: As per my knowledge hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update only update the schema if exist.

Comment: No it can also create the schema try it once